# How do I put chromedriver in PATH

Tags: google-chrome

This is in `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="/home/<usr>/Documents/chromedriver/chromedriver"
```

Yet in Python, I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Specs:

```
(env) user@computer:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: *"executable needs to be in PATH"* is a bit misleading tbh - it's the directory **containing** the executable that needs to be in PATH

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Yes I know I am a seasoned user on this website. I'll get back to you shortly

Comment: I have added information