# How to add chromedriver to Path in ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04

I have tried to add the path of chrome driver in Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

1. [How do I put chromedriver in PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228099/how-do-i-put-chromedriver-in-path)

its located at

```
/home/<usr>/Documents/Python/chromedriver
```

in my laptop

can any one help me with the solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you downloaded und extracted [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) you have three options.

- **A)** Save the file in a directory which is already in `PATH`
- **B)** Save the file at a custom location and add it to `PATH`
- **C)** Save the file at a custom location and create a symlink to the file in one of the directories that are already in `PATH`

For the following examples let's assume the extracted file is in `~/Downloads`

**Example to A)**

```
// Move file to a directory that's already in PATH
sudo mv ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/bin

// Make file executable
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

**Example to B)**

```
// Move file to a directory that's not in PATH
mv ~/Downloads/chromedriver ~/Documents/Python/ChromeDriver/

// Make file executable
chmod +x ~/Documents/Python/ChromeDriver/chromedriver

// Add directory to PATH
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/Documents/Python/ChromeDriver:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

**Example to C)**

```
// Move file to a directory that's not in PATH
mv ~/Downloads/chromedriver ~/Documents/Python/ChromeDriver/

// Make file executable
chmod +x ~/Documents/Python/ChromeDriver/chromedriver

// Create a symlink to 'chromedriver' in one of the directories 
// that are already in PATH (e.g. /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin)
sudo ln -s ~/Documents/Python/ChromeDriver/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

I hope i could make it clear.

Comment: Example to C) worked as solution

Comment: I'm glad i could help you. Actually, all three of them should work.